# Crashing when improper input given more than once

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to make a simple number guesser program, it works pretty well however if I enter 'a' twice instead of a valid int it crashes out. Can someone explain what I'm doing wrong here.

```
import random

def input_sanitiser():
    guess = input("Please enter a number between 1 and 10: ")
    while True:
        if type(guess) != int:
            guess = int(input("That isn't a number, try again: "))
        elif guess not in range (1,11):
            guess = int(input("This is not a valid number, try again: "))
        else:
            break

def main():
    number = random.randrange(1,10)
    guess = 0
    input_sanitiser()
    while guess != number:
        if guess < number:
            print("This number is too low!")
            input_sanitiser()
        if guess > number:
            print("This number is too high!")
            input_sanitiser()
        else: 
            break
    print ("Congratulations, you've guessed correctly")





if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: In `input_sanitiser`, `guess` will always be a `str` at first; `type()` doesn't check whether it's convertible to `int`, only that it is in fact an `int`. Use `try/except` instead

Comment: @BallpointBen `catch` is not Python. Did you mean `except`?

Comment: Thanks I edited my comment

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to check the input before trying to convert it to `int`:

```
int(input("This is not a valid number, try again: "))
```

I would write:

```
while True:
    try:
        guess = int(input("This is not a valid number, try again: "))
    except ValueError:
        pass
    else:
        break
```

---

Side note: the code isn't working as expected:

```
def main():
    number = random.randrange(1,10)
    guess = 0
    input_sanitiser()  # <<<<<<<<<<
    while guess != number:
```

Note that `input_sanitiser` does not modify the variable `guess` in `main`, you need some other way round, like processing the input then returning the result from `input_sanitiser`, like this:

```
def input_sanitiser():
    guess = input("Please enter a number between 1 and 10: ")
    while True:
        try:
            guess = int(input("This is not a valid number, try again: "))
        except ValueError:
            continue  # keep asking for a valid number

        if guess not in range(1, 11):
            print("number out of range")
            continue
        break
    return guess

def main():
    number = random.randrange(1,10)
    guess = input_sanitiser()
    while guess != number:
        if guess < number:
            print("This number is too low!")
            guess = input_sanitiser()
        if guess > number:
            print("This number is too high!")
            guess = input_sanitiser()
        else: 
            break
    print ("Congratulations, you've guessed correctly")
```

Comment: This was very helpful thank you, wasn't sure how to pass variables, thank you!